# Who is The Best youth scout (stat wise)

Tags: football-manager-2015

Hey I'm currently doing a career with Leeds and I want to make a youth team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What type of a budget do you have to play with?
Try Looking for scouts with (20) at The youth stats 
Or get a young youth scout and grow him up.

Comment: Oh and if that doesn't work search online